# Expanding stack with list comprehensions

Tags: python, python-3.8, perfect-square

How to explain that list comperhensions expression does not work (python 3.8.2 32bit env):

```
def perfect_squares(max_psqare):
   psqares = [0]
   return [psqares.append(psqares[-1] + 2 * i - 1) for i in range(1, int(max_psqare ** 0.5) + 1)]
```

in contrast to:

```
def perfect_squares(max_psqare):
   psqares = [0]
   max_base = int(max_psqare ** 0.5)
   for i in range(1, max_base + 1):
      psqares.append(psqares[-1] + 2 * i - 1)
   return psqares
```

First one gives array of None values?
Comperhension expression does not have access to psqares stack?

Comment: `list.append` returns `None`. Your list comprehension is gathering the `None`s resulting from each append. Your `psqares` has the values.

Comment: @DimitrisFasarakisHilliard, you are right. Thank you!